# Json Libgdx serialize / de-serialize a Object Map of Object Maps

Tags: java, libgdx, data-structure, serialization, json

Any one have any ideas on how I can serialize / de-serialize an

```
ObjectMap<Enum, ObjectMap<String, Object>>();
```

(Object is usually a String Integer or Vector2 ) using libgdx's built in json classes?. On de-serialize the inner ObjectMap, is always null even though the values are written to the json file.

Comment: Usually I convert my map to a list of key-value pairs, and serialize that. Have you tried anything similar?

Comment: yes But I really don't know how  to properly do that

Comment: Then show us what you tried, and we can help you with what's next.

Comment: I thought libgx classes  were automatically serializable  via json.

Comment: had someone have told  me libgdx json can't de-serialize Enums I would have solved. this days ago

Comment: Sounds like you found a solution. Please post it as an Answer below, so it can help other devs who run into similar trouble.

Answer (score 2):

libGDX Json converts Enums to strings and therefore cannot serialize / de-serialize  Map keys to anything but strings.

To fix this, either...

1. Use strings for keys in Maps (ObjectMap, HashMap ect.).
2. Use GSON, which can serialize Enum Map Keys just fine.
3. Write lots of special serialization / de-serialization code using a class that implements `Json.Serializer<T>` where `T` is your map and then register that with your  libGDX Json instance.

I recommend option one or two.